# Multi-camera system - How can I determine the distance and angles between each camera?

Tags: camera-calibration

I am new to camera calibration. I really appreciate your advice.

I have 4 cameras mounted on the roof of a vehicle.

Cam1, Cam2, Cam3, Cam4

The images captured from each camera overlaps with one next to it. That is, the images captured from Cam1 overlap with those captured from Cam2, and Cam2 overlaps with Cam1 and Cam3 etc.

I want to know the intrinsic parameters of each camera and the distance and angles between each camera.

I know that to get the intrisic parameters of each camera I can use Jean-Yves Bouguet's Camera Calibration Toolbox for Matlab. But how can I find the distance and angles between each camera?

Can I just drive the vehicle and capture the images from all the camera and use structure-from-motion to compute the 3D positions of each camera, then determine the distances and angles among each other? Or should I use multi-camera calibration techniques that are freely available? I found such as

- Multi-Camera Self-Calibration (http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~svoboda/SelfCal/)
- Kalibr calibration toolbox (https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr)
- CamOdoCal (http://people.inf.ethz.ch/hengli/camodocal/)
  etc

Any suggestion on multi-camera calibration is greatly appreciated, or pass me a link that easily explains this is also helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried stereo calibration with your camera array configuration (pair-wise), that is, stereo calibrate cam1 and cam2, then cam2 and cam3, etc. If this is not useful for you, try the method proposed by:
(http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~svoboda/SelfCal/). Hope it helps

Comment: @trox Thanks for your reply. Stereo calibration is possible but it doesn't impose the constraint that all cameras go together. Yes, I found Svoboda work interesting but it needs a dark room to calibrate it which is not possible for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Kalibr calibration toolbox may be useful for your case. You can refer to the multi camera calibration example provided at the [wiki](https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr/wiki/multiple-camera-calibration). The sample dataset used in the example run consists of four cameras.